# Linker does not see template function defined in a base (pure virtual) class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here's the code:

```
class PureDummy
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
        template<class T>
        void bar();
};

class Dummy : public PureDummy
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() 
        {

        }
        template<class T>
        void bar()
        {

        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PureDummy *pdummy = new Dummy();
    pdummy->foo(); //OK
    //pdummy->bar<int>();  //undefined reference to `void PureDummy::bar<int>()'
}
```

So as a comment states, with a call to bar compilation fails.

1. Why does the template function exhibit different behavior from a "regular" **foo** function?
2. Is it possible to "point" that there's an implementation in the derived class?

Comment: bar is not virtual and(!) you can not make a template function virtual (the number of possible instantiations is unknown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static type of `pdummy` is `PureDummy *` so the compiler will first check the `PureDummy` class for such a function. One exists and is accessible so it will attempt the call. The function is non-virtual (templates can't be virtual) so it will attempt to call `PureDummy::bar`. This function has no definition so the link fails with the undefined symbol error.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `PureDUmmy::bar` and haven't provided a definition of it.

The in-practice result is a linking error.

In order to be able to override a function in a derived class for runtime polymorphism (as you're apparently attempting with the call via a pointer to base class), it needs to be `virtual`. C++ does not support templating of a `virtual` function. One possible solution, applicable in some cases, is to replace runtime polymorphism with compile time polymorphism, and use CRTP.

Comment: I don't think so. A Dummy object is instantiate and foo() is defined in Dummy.

Comment: I am providing a definition to foo. In fact, it's being called correctly and no problem with compilation arises. I'm asking about **bar**.